# Correct way to Log Exceptions .Net core MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, .net-core, try-catch

When I catch exceptions I'm currently logging at every level. 
I'm not sure this is correct or just 'making noise' in logging. 
If I throw exceptions then log at the controller layer (not service & repository layers) will this capture all the exceptions by bubbling up?

**Controller Layer**

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        new ErrorReporter("MVC", ex.ToString(), User.Identity);

        errorMsgList.Add(ex.Message);
        foreach (var item in ex.Data.Values)
        {
            errorMsgList.Add(item.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**Repository & Service Layer**

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    new ErrorReporter("MVC", ex.ToString(), null);
    throw;
}
```

Here's a sample of my logs in the database

[image]

Comment: What does the ErrorReporter class do? You could use filters or middleware instead of adding exception handling in your controllers.

Comment: You can find an example here https://github.com/jasontaylordev/NorthwindTraders/blob/master/Src/WebUI/Common/CustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs

Comment: Thank you, I like this, it also brought to my attention I hadn't made my ErrorReporter async. So ErrorReporter just performs a sql insert